# When Does DetailController Change Size After Rotation to Landscape?

Tags: uitableview, ios6, master-detail, autolayout

I'm running into a bit of an issue with the Master-Detail layout for an iPad app I'm writing.  The DetailController contains a UIViewController that manages a tableview.  The tableview contains custom cells, and the layout is very specific.

I'm using auto-layout, and the hopes were to use auto-layout to manage the cell layout on transition from portrait to landscape, but that seems to be a complete bust.  No matter what I do, I can't seem to get a layout configuration to work where the table is resized on rotation.  The size is stuck at whatever the width and height are defined as in the Size Inspector for that table.

Sooo ... I'm trying to make it work on my own.  But I can't figure out when the Display Controller actually resizes itself. No matter where I check, when I get the size of the Display Controller, the width and height are fixed at the original size for portrait mode.

I'm not sure what to do at this point.  If someone has an idea for how to use auto-layout to make the table layout work automatically, that'd be killer.  But I think I'd be satisfied at this point if someone could show me how to resize the table manually after rotation.